# Let $X,Y \sim \operatorname{Expo}(\lambda)$ i.i.d, and $T = X + Y$, $W = X/Y$. Find joint and marginal PDF of $T$ and $W$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be i.i.d. $\operatorname{Expo}(\lambda)$, and transform them to $T = X + Y$, $W = X/Y$ .
>
> (a) Find the joint PDF of $T$ and $W$ . Are they independent?
>
> (b) Find the marginal PDFs of $T$ and $W$ .

a) I obtain as the (absolute) value of the determinant of the Jacobian $\frac{t}{(1+w)^2}$. The backtransformation is $x=\frac{tw}{1+w}$ and $y=\frac{t}{1+w}$. Thus, using the change of variables formula and the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, I get

\begin{align}
f_{T,W}(t,w) &= f_X \left(\frac{tw}{1+w} \right) f_Y \left(\frac{t}{1+w} \right) \frac{t}{(1+w)^2} \\
&= \lambda \operatorname{exp} \left(-\lambda \frac{tw}{1+w} \right) \lambda \operatorname{exp} \left(-\lambda \frac{t}{1+w} \right) \frac{t}{(1+w)^2} \\
&= \lambda^2 \operatorname{exp}(-\lambda t) \frac{t}{(1+w)^2}
\end{align}

Thus, $T$ and $W$ are independent, and to find the marginal distribution, we just need to find the right integration constants. I found that we just have to separate the terms above, so

$$
f_T(t) = \lambda^2 t \operatorname{exp}(-\lambda t) \quad t \geq 0
$$

$$
f_W(w) = \frac{1}{(1+w)^2}  \quad w \geq 0
$$

Is this correct? If so, what are the distributions for $T$ and $W$? Do they have names?

Comment: Why downvoted ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct.  $T$ is very clearly a gamma distribution with shape parameter $2$ and rate parameter $\lambda$.  $W$ is a special case of a number of distributions; for instance, it can be regarded as a Pareto-type distribution, or a log-logistic distribution for a suitable choice of parameters.

[See the following PDF](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~nydic001/docs/unpubs/Ratio_of_Exponentials.pdf)  for a more detailed discussion.

Comment: Thank you, for the gamma, I have to improve my pattern recognition skills. I find it hard to recognize its pdf. I'll have a look at your pdf.