# If $X+Y$ follows exponential distribution with parameter $2 \lambda$, is it necessary $X$ and $Y$ follow exponential with parameter $\lambda$?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, solution-verification

Let $Z=X+Y$, $Z \backsim exp(2 \lambda)$, with $X, Y$ i.i.d. Then, $$f_Z(Z=z)=2 \lambda e^{-2 \lambda(x+y)}$$ By the convolution function, $$f_Z(Z=z) = \int\limits_{- \infty}^{\infty}f_Y(z-x)f_X(x)dx $$
$$ \implies 2 \lambda e^{-2 \lambda(x+y)} = \int\limits_{- \infty}^{\infty}f_Y(z-x)f_X(x)dx$$
Differentiating both sides,
$$-4 {\lambda}^2e^{-2 \lambda (x+y)} = f_Y(z-x)f_X(x)$$  Since $Y=Z-X$ and $X, Y$ are independent,
$f_Y(z-x)f_X(x) = f(x,y)$, the joint pdf. Then,
$$f_X(x)=\int\limits_{- \infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)dy$$
$$f_X(x)=\int\limits_0^{\infty}-4 {\lambda}^2e^{-2 \lambda (x+y)}$$
$$f_X(x)= -4 {\lambda}^2e^{-2 \lambda x}\int\limits_0^{\infty}e^{-2 \lambda y}dy$$
Put $2 \lambda y = u,$ then, $dy = \frac{1}{2 \lambda}du$
$$f_X(x)= -4 {\lambda}^2e^{-2 \lambda x}.\frac{1}{2 \lambda}$$
$$f_X(x) = -2{\lambda}e^{-2 \lambda x}$$

What am I doing wrong that my marginal function for $X$ is not integrating to $1$? More importantly, is the general approach that I have taken to solving this problem correct?

Comment: Use Fourier transform (characteristic function), $\phi_z(t) = E(e^{itZ}) = E(e^{itX}) E(e^{itY}) = \phi(t)^2,$ where $\phi$ is the c.f. of $X$ and $Y.$ By taking square root, you will get the result (or take Laplace transform instead)

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. exponentially distributed, then  $X + Y$ is **not** exponentially distributed.

Comment: @hans engler’s comment does answer your question. Also, that is not how you differentiate both sides of an equation. And maybe mention you’re setting $z=x+y$.

Comment: @AvijitDikey the approach you took is correct but far from a smart one. It is prone to many mistakes (you probably made a few and __I will not check your calculations__). Also notice that the sum of i.i.d. Exponential is gamma-distributed

Comment: $\min(X,Y) \sim\mathsf{Exp}(2\lambda)$ [by the CDF method] and $X + Y \sim \mathsf{Exp}(\mathrm{shape}=2,\mathrm{rate}=\lambda)$ [by multiplying MGFs.]

Comment: Transformation method for sum of exponential distributions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098232/let-x-y-sim-operatornameexpo-lambda-i-i-d-and-t-x-y-w-x-y-f?rq=1)--one of the 'Related' links in the margin. // It is easier to use moment generating functions.

Answer (score 1):

*Comment continued* for graphs from simulation of a million realizations of $\min(X,Y)$ and $X+Y)$. Let the rate parameter be $\lambda = 2:$

```
set.seed(2021)
x = rexp(10^6, 2)
y = rexp(10^6, 2)

v = pmin(x,y)
summary(v)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
0.000001 0.071936 0.173254 0.249623 0.345963 3.215256 

s = x + y
summary(s)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
0.000699 0.480684 0.839341 0.999689 1.346056 9.329743
```

Notice that $E(X) = E(Y) = 1/2 = 1/\lambda; E(V) = 1/4 = \frac{1}{2\lambda}, E(S) = 1 = 1/\lambda + 1/\lambda.$

[image]

R code for figure:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 hist(v, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", 
      main="Exponential Dist'n of min(X,Y)")
   curve(dexp(x, 4), add=T, col="red", lwd=2, n=10001)
 hist(s, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", ylim=c(0,.8), 
       main="Gamma Dist'n of X + Y")
   curve(dgamma(x, 2, 2), add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```